# How to calculate the whole run time in a specific notebook?

Tags: notebooks

I have found a way to show the run time in a specific cell in a notebook (.nb).

Now, I want to have the whole run time including all cells in a specific notebook.

How is it possible to calculate it ? Is there any special functions or commands or options ?

Comment: You can have `t = AbsoluteTime[]` at the beginning and `AbsoluteTime[] - t` at the end.  Or do you need timings for each cell separately?

Comment: @Szabolcs tic...toc :-)

Comment: Try `SessionTime[]`.

Comment: `SessionTime` would be equivalent to `AbsoluteTime` in this case. You would still need `t  =SessionTime[];` at the beginning and `SessionTime[]  -t` at the end.

Answer (score 10):

If you enable the display of timings in Options:

[image: options]

your notebook will show when the first cell started to evaluate and when the last cell finished.

[image: top cell timing]

[image: bottom cell timing]

I think you need an extra blank cell at the bottom to get the last value.

If you can't do this sum in your head, perhaps there's a way to extract the times using `CellLabel`...

Comment: Thank you all! I'm trying all the tricks you said right now.

Comment: @Szabolcs : I think `t = AbsoluteTime[]` at the beginning and `AbsoluteTime[] - t` at the end, is the best way to calculate the whole run time in a notebook(.nb) with high accuracy. Thank you Szabolcs, again !